# Are AngularJs $q promises compatible with async/await?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

I'm working in an Angular/AngularJs hybrid application with TypeScript (versions 9.07, 1.5.11, and 3.7.5, respectively). All of our HTTP requests, even the ones made from new Angular components, use a wrapper service implemented in plain Javascript, originally developed along with the "legacy" AngularJs side of the application, whose methods return $q promises generated by the AngularJs $http service. Since that service is plain Javascript, typing of return values isn't a problem, since TypeScript considers them just an `any`, which it's perfectly happy to let me cast as an `IPromise<TReturnType>`.

My question is whether those promises are fully compatible with the `async` and `await` keywords in TypeScript. Trying it out with simple examples seemed to work fine, but I'm concerned about corner-case problems that would only show up at runtime using those keywords with non-native Promises.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compatibility with `async` is not an issue, as that keyword does not directly depend on an existing promise instance: it makes the corresponding function return a newly created EcmaScript Promise object.

If an `async` function returns a thenable, then the returned native promise will have its resolution made dependent on that thenable.

You can see that latter effect in this snippet:

```js
async function test() {
    let thenable = { then: cb => cb(13) };
    return thenable;
}

let result = test();
console.log(result instanceof Promise);
result.then(console.log); // 13
```

The `await` keyword can be used with an expression that returns a thenable, so also in that case there is no requirement to have an EcmaScript compatible promise:

```js
async function test() {
    let thenable = { then: cb => cb(13) };
    let value = await thenable;
    console.log(value); // 13
}

test();
```

So in conclusion, both keywords will recognise a thenable and deal with it as expected. There is no requirement that this thenable is an instance of the native Promise.

Surely `$q` promises are thenables, so that is just fine.