# Angular JS - returning results from an async operation

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

Angular JS - 1.6.9

Have been working on this for hours, confessedly, I am very not practised in Angular JS and would appreciate some guidance.

I have an element that every time information is updated in fields across a form, it will update a "preview pane" using the information from those fields, reading a template file, and substituting the values, printing that information to said preview pane. (Note: right now I'm reading every time every field is updated in any way, and I know this is bad, and later after I get THIS working, I will work on caching. So, I am not asking for help on this part, cos I know I have to address it and will later.)

I've tried this in so many ways and this is most recent attempt, after hours of fiddling and I just keep getting `undefined` as a result to my console.

I am pretty confident this really just has to do with my absolute misunderstanding of asynchronous things.

I have had debugging info in fillTemplate() and it does successfully read the file, just, it is not getting to the browser.

HTML:

```html
<div class="col text-monospace small shadow p-2 mb-2 pre-scrollable">
    {{updateItemInformation()}}
</div>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller('c', ($scope, $sce) => {
    $scope.updateItemInformation = async () => {
        let result ;

        const maxLineLength = 80;

        result = await fillTemplate($scope.item) ;

        console.log(result) ;

        return result ;
    };

    async function fillTemplate(item) {
        let result = "";

        const response = await fetch(`./templates/${item.category}.template`)
        const template = await response.text()

        if(!template) return "";

        return template ;
    }
```

Comment: You mention it successfully reads the file. As in your fetch returns successfully? Have you tried wrapping your awaits inside of a try-catch to ensure its not swallowing an error? You may have better luck instead of depending on the template to trigger your async function; bind to a string in the scope, update that string from your update function, and trigger the update via an event. That way you aren't fighting the digest cycle for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be with AngularJS not recognizing updates made by your async function. You'll need to trigger Angular's `digest cycle` manually using `$scope.$apply()` after your async operation.

Here's a more streamlined version of your code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller('c', ($scope) => {
    $scope.updateItemInformation = async () => {
        const result = await fillTemplate($scope.item);
        console.log(result);
        $scope.$apply(() => {
            $scope.template = result;
        });
    };

    async function fillTemplate(item) {
        const response = await fetch(`./templates/${item.category}.template`);
        return response.text();
    }
});
```

In your HTML:

```
<div class="col text-monospace small shadow p-2 mb-2 pre-scrollable">
    {{template}}
    <button ng-click="updateItemInformation()">Refresh Preview</button>
</div>
```

Added a button to trigger the update and display the result in `{{template}}`. Hope this helps! Keep going; you're on the right track!

Comment: This does seem to work, but I'm wondering if I can get this to do it as I was hoping without having to click the button. I'm fine with the overhead this introduces. It's not a large application. I'll award you the bounty for this response though! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS, does not inherently support asynchronous programming using the async/await syntax that is commonly used in modern JavaScript frameworks. Use the `$q` service to build promises and `$http` for  XMLHttpRequest.

The following example is just a general reference about building promises (async calls) in the AngularJS way. It is not a literal solution.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller('c', ($scope, $sce, $http, $log) => {
  $ctrl.$onInit = () => {
    $scope.template = '';
    $scope.updateItemInformation = updateItemInformation;
  }

  function updateItemInformation() {
    fillTemplate($scope.item)
      .then(response => {
        $scope.template = response;
      })
      .catch(error => {
         $log.error(error)
      });
  }

  function fillTemplate(item) {
    const _deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get(`./templates/${item.category}.template`)
      .then(response => {
        if (!response) _deferred.reject('Template not found');
        _deferred.resolve(response)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        _deferred.reject(error)
      })
    return _deferred.promise;
  }
}
```

Comment: Inherently, no. Implicitly, yes. You can still use async-await keywords with promises returned by $q. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62177913/are-angularjs-q-promises-compatible-with-async-await